# Function within a variable to create a mouseover event

Tags: jquery, function, variables, mouseover, mouseout

I'm attempting to create a mouseover event function that contains a variable. I plan on using if and else to achieve the mouseover and mouseleave (or out). I've attempted to explain this further at this link in the //comments.  http://jsfiddle.net/EsEBY/14/

jQuery:

```
var n = $("#block").mouseover(function () {});

if (n) { //if variable n (mouseover) occurs on #block, make #block opacity 1
$("#block").css("opacity", "1"),
alert("Working!");
} else { //else #block opacity .5
$("#block").css("opacity", ".5");
}
```

CSS:

```
#block {
width:5em;
height:5em;
background:#CCC;
margin:1em;
}
```

I've probably got this all wrong but am trying to do this in a different way from .hover method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is

```
$("#block").hover(function () {
    $(this).css("opacity", "1");
}, function(){
    $(this).css("opacity", ".5");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/httpy/)

The `mouseover` does not work like that, the code that is suppose to run on mouse over has to be in the callback function passed to the event.

In your case you need to change the opacity to 1 when mouser enter to #block and it has to changed to .5 when mouse leaves, for this purpose you can use the [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) event handlers

Comment: Thanks for the reply Arun P Johny. This should help me in figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply trying to change the opacity on mouseover using jQuery, then this is probably what you are trying to do:

```
$("#block").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).css('opacity', '1');
}).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).css('opacity', '.5');
});
```

However, this is probably better accomplished with CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
#block {
    opacity: .5;
}

#block:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Hey Seth, thanks for your reply. I'm instead looking to pass the css hover as I would like to achieve it via javascript / jQuery as tablets, mobile cannot detect .hover.